# Orthogonality, Maximization and Eigen-Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, orthonormal

I Have read that for a matrix of reals $Y$ and a p.s.d matrix $B$ that the

Maximum of  $ f(Y)=Tr(Y^TBY)$ subject to $Y^TY = I$ is achieved when $span(Y)$ equals the span of the first $d$ eigen-vectors of $B$.

What is the reasoning behind this eigen-solution leading to the maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathrm{tr} \, Y^T B Y = \mathrm{tr} \, B Y Y^T$, and $Y Y^T$ is a rank-$d$ orthogonal projection; any such projection is obtained in this way. So you maximize $\mathrm{tr} \, BP$ among rank-$d$ orthogonal projections $P$, so it's a consequence of the [Courant minimax principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_minimax_principle) for the eigenvalues, or of the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem), if you want...